# JSPlumb Endpoint Multiple Connections

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

i have some `div` elements which i want to connect them via [JSPlumb Community Edition](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/). i have these line of codes in javascript:

```
$("#create_item").click(function() {
    var $i = "item" + counter;
    var $txt = "Create " + counter;
    var $div = $("<div>", {id: $i, class: "box create", text: $txt});
    $(".container").append($div);
    counter++;
    jsPlumb.ready(function() {
        jsPlumb.draggable($i, {containment:"parent"});
        jsPlumb.addEndpoint($i, { 
            anchor:"Right" },
            sourceEndpointOptions);
    });
});

$("#dispose_item").click(function() {
    var $i = "item" + counter;
    var $txt = "Dispose " + counter;
    var $div = $("<div>", {id: $i, class: "box dispose", text: $txt});
    $(".container").append($div);
    counter++;
    jsPlumb.ready(function() {
        jsPlumb.draggable($i, {containment:"parent"});
        jsPlumb.addEndpoint($i, { 
            anchor:"Left" },
            targetEndpointOptions);
    });
});

var sourceEndpointOptions = {
    endpoint:"Dot",
    paintStyle:{ width:15, height:15, fillStyle:'#666' },
    isSource:true,
    connectorStyle : { strokeStyle:"#666" },
    isTarget:false
};

var targetEndpointOptions = {
    endpoint:"Dot",
    paintStyle:{ width:15, height:15, fillStyle:'#460CE8' },
    isSource:false,
    connectorStyle : { strokeStyle:"#460CE8" },
    isTarget:true
};
```

and what i want to do is making two `#create_tem` and one `#dispose_item` in runtime and connect the the two source endpoint to the target endpoint, but when i connect one source to the target, the target won't accept the second source. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was missing `maxConnections:-1` in the End Point Options!